# include country code as array & store view as switch cases

Tags: php, magento

we are assigning 5 store views for 200 countries using below code.

now I am following as below code where `IN, AT, IR, AU` are country codes. `usa, canada` are store views.

like this I need to assign each **country code** for one **store view** for all 200+ countries. Is there any way i can use array and use only 5 switch cases & include many country codes in one switch case.

```
switch ($cnCode) {

                case "IN": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('usa');
                    break;
                }


                case "AT": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('usa');
                    break;
                 }

                case "IR": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('usa');
                    break;
                }


                case "AU": {
                    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('canada');
                    break;
                }
            }
```

also i am fine with any other way with less code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
if (in_array($enCode, array('IN', 'AT', 'IR'))) {
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('usa');
}
if (in_array($enCode, array('AU'))) {
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('canada');
}
```

Or you could combine you cases:

```
switch ($enCode) {
    case 'IN':
    case 'AT':
    case 'IR':
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('usa');
        break;
    case 'AU':
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('canada');
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. which one you prefer, `in_array` or `switch case`

Comment: I think combining the cases using the `switch` statement would be easier to read. With the `in_array` method you'll end up with quite long (wide) lines which according to [psr-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) lines should 80 characters or less anyway.